# How to use bullet in gazebo 3.0?

Tags: gazebo, ubuntu

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

How to select bullet as a physics engine in gazebo 3.0? I am using ubuntu 13.04 with gazebo installed from debian. Also ran the bullet installation from [here](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/3.0/install).

If I do it from the world file, with the tag

```
<physics type="bullet">
```

gazebo does not starts without giving any error.

starting it with:

```
$ gazebo -e bullet
```

it runs with the default one, ODE. Following code outputs 'ode'

```
this->world->GetPhysicsEngine()->GetType()
```

Cheers,
Andrei

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5938/how-to-use-bullet-in-gazebo-3.0-?/) by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 2108 on 2014-04-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

To get the support for physics engine different than ODE, a full from source installation of gazebo is needed, since it has to built the binary support at compilation time. I'm afraid that you can not use the debs to get this kind of support.

The good news is that is in [our roadmap for Gazebo 4.0](http://gazebosim.org/#status) to implement plugin support the physics engines, so hopefully you can do this from .debs in the future.

I've clarified the need of a from source installation in our install document a bit more.
Thanks Andrei.

---

Originally posted by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) with karma: 1485 on 2014-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2014-04-16**:
It makes sense, thanks for the answer :) And having a plugin type support of the physics engines won't slow down the simulation?

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2014-04-16**:
When speaking about plugins, think on dynamic symbol loading, which should happen just once and load the library in memory (via dlopen). I would say that it won't mean a big overhead speaking about performance.